# Add dependencies to jar Class-Path manifest

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, classpath, build.gradle

When I try to add dependencies to jar manifest class-path it is throwing an exception:

Use:

gradle 2.1

build:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Main',
                   'Implementation-Version': version,
                   'Main-Class': 'com.apl.Main',
                   'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' ')
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs','test_libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile name: 'bcmail-jdk16-dss'
    compile name: 'bcprov-jdk16-dss'
    compile name: 'bctsp-jdk16-dss'
}
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: You can't change configuration 'compile' because it is already resolved!
```

Can anyone help me resolve this issue please?

Answer (score 2):

try to put

`dependencies {
    compile name: 'bcmail-jdk16-dss'
    compile name: 'bcprov-jdk16-dss'
    compile name: 'bctsp-jdk16-dss'
}`

before

```
    jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Main',
                   'Implementation-Version': version,
                   'Main-Class': 'com.apl.Main',
                   'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' ')
    }
}
```